# Installing multiple Python 3 kernels in iPython/Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have Python 3.7 and 3.8 on my system.

I have run pip install on both 3.7 and 3.8 for jupyter notebook, however when trying to create a new notebook, the kernel list only shows one value for "Python 3"

How do I get both Python 3.7 and 3.8 to show up here?

Comment: Found any answer to this ?

Comment: Yes, see answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to install the kernel on jupyter.
You can do this in command prompt/bash terminal:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

This will return all the currently installed kernels for jupyter notebooks.

It's best to run a virtual environment for each project you have. Activate your venv, and then you can install the Python kernel for use within a jupyter notebook with this bash command:

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname
```

Note this installed kernel will also be available to jupyter when from outside the venv.

You can uninstall kernels with the following:

```
jupyter kernelspec uninstall <name of kernel>
```

See here for more details: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

There are also instructions in there for installing multiple python kernels without using a virtual environment.